# removing each . after ] appear in a line in complete text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file in which I need to eliminate . after the ] on every line

e.g

```
xyz[1.2]35.23
xyz[1.2.3]35.234
```

output should be

```
xyz[1.2]3523
xyz[1.2.3]35234
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the dots after the right-most `]`:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\(][^]]*\)\.\([^]]*\)$/\1\2/;t1'
```

Or:

```
awk -F']' -vOFS=']' 'NF>1 {gsub(/\./,"",$NF)};1'
```

Or:

```
perl -pe 's/.*\]\K.*/$&=~s|\.||gr/e'
```

To remove after `]` regardless of whether there are other `]` at the right.

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\(].*\)\./\1/;t1'
```

Or:

```
perl -pe 's/.*?\]\K.*/$&=~s|\.||gr/e'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=])\d+\K\.//g' file
xyz[1.2]3523
xyz[1.2.3]35234
```

Comment: Note that it only replaces one `.` after each `]`. (turns `]1.2.3` to `]12.3`, but `]1.2]2.3`  to `]12]23`)